# Is there any function that restore soft deleted record from repository design pattern?

Tags: laravel, restore, soft-delete

I use repository design pattern in my code, and now, I want restore my soft deleted records. but I couldn't find any solution for this problem use repository design pattern.I use apiato http://apiato.io/ framework that based on laravel. I want to restore my record on Task.

This is my Model class

```php
class Property extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

And this is my repositry codes for delete.

```php
class DeletePropertyTask extends Task
{

    protected $repository;

    public function __construct(PropertyRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function run($id)
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->repository->delete($id);
            return $result;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new DeleteResourceFailedException(null, null, null, null, $e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In apiato repository class there is method name `makeModel()`
when you call this method, everty things change to eloquent functions. after that you can use `withTrash` method to search between soft deleted records and find specific record that you want, after that call `restore()` method.

```php
$this->repository->makeModel()->withTrash()->where('id',$property_id')->first()->restore();
```

Answer (score 2):

To restore a soft deleting record from the task

```
$this->repository::withTrashed()->findorfail($id)->restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent has a way of restoring soft deleted entries using the `restore()` function. Here is the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models) link for more info.

Comment: apiato repository class different from eloquent , and there is not exist some methods. and this not work fine

Comment: It is not `withTrash()` but `withTrashed()` be careful with the method spelling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want restore a soft deleting record, you can use restore() property.

```
public function restore($id)
{
    $this->repository->find($id)->restore();
}
```

[more information](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Comment: In apiato repository class, if record soft deleted, not return in simple find. and should be use withTrash method, that withTrash method not exist also.